# Convert System.Drawing.Color to System.Windows.Media.Color

Tags: .net, system.drawing, system.windows.media

```
System.Drawing.Color drawRedColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
System.Windows.Media.Color mediaColor = ?drawRedColor.ToMediaColor();?
```

Comment: @serhio - please, in the future, state your question in words.

Comment: Only that some people will see this and not see a question (so may vote to close as "not a real question"). Don't forget that we also want these questions to be found by google, and asking an actual question will help with getting this question in search results.

Comment: @Oded: I didn't find things to comment here.

Comment: @Oded: do *you* think that this is not a question?

Comment: Do you see a close vote?

Comment: @Oded, ok man, I think we understood each other :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

How about:

```
using MColor = System.Windows.Media.Color;
using DColor = System.Drawing.Color;
...

public static MColor ToMediaColor(this DColor color)
{
   return MColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

EDIT: Fixed the 'unpacking' of the ARGB.

Comment: No overload for method 'FromArgb' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @serhio: You're right, sorry. How about now?

Comment: @Ani: don't see a really need for "using"s here :)

Comment: @serhio: I agree. It was mainly to prevent the horizontal scroll-bar from appearing. :)

Comment: @Ani break your code line in two ;) but I understand, is OK :)

Comment: What happens when the input is Color.Empty?

Comment: @Mike Post: Works fine, as expected. `Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.Color.Empty.ToMediaColor());` - Output: `#00000000`.

Answer (score 8):

```
System.Windows.Media.Color mediaColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(Color.Red.R, Color.Red.G, Color.Red.B);
```

Comment: not correct approach, I don't need to transform the *Red* color, but a color variable :)

Comment: hmmm... maybe you should extrapolate on the answer as I extrapolated on the "question" :)