# How to convert from System.Drawing.Color to System.Windows.Media.Color?

Tags: c#, colors

How can I convert between these two color types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Drawing.Color => System.Windows.Media.Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104910/system-drawing-color-system-windows-media-color)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can see examples of both of the conversion directions below:

**`Drawing.Color` to `Windows.Media.Color`**

```
// This is your color to convert from
System.Drawing.Color color; 
System.Windows.Media.Color newColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

**`Windows.Media.Color` to `Drawing.Color`**

```
// This is your color to convert from
System.Windows.Media.Color color; 
System.Drawing.Color newColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Answer (score 15):

For frequent use i suggest helper like this:

```
using SDColor = System.Drawing.Color;
using SWMColor = System.Windows.Media.Color;

namespace ColorHelper
{
    public static class ColorExt
    {
        public static SWMColor ToSWMColor(this SDColor color) => SWMColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
        public static SDColor ToSDColor(this SWMColor color) => SDColor.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

... or use @Rion Williams answer as an extension:

```
public static System.Windows.Media.Brush ToBrush(this System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace HQ.Wpf.Util
{
    public static class ColorExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Media Color (WPF) to Drawing Color (WinForm)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mediaColor"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static System.Drawing.Color ToDrawingColor(this System.Windows.Media.Color mediaColor)
        {
            return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(mediaColor.A, mediaColor.R, mediaColor.G, mediaColor.B);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Drawing Color (WPF) to Media Color (WinForm)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="drawingColor"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static System.Windows.Media.Color ToMediaColor(this System.Drawing.Color drawingColor)
        {
            return System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(drawingColor.A, drawingColor.R, drawingColor.G, drawingColor.B);
        }
```