# How to compare a System.Drawing.Color and a System.Windows.Media.Color?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

How to test whether a `System.Drawing.Color` and a `System.Windows.Media.Color` describe the same colour?

I tried

```
colour1 == colour2
```

but I get an error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Drawing.Color' and 'System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: Two different types of Object.

Comment: Hi Ani. The question you suggest is a duplicate is nonsense - it doesn't even contain any words!

Comment: @ColonelPanic, using the suggested duplicate as a reference this would be pretty easy to solve. It seem like you have put any effort in yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Convert from one type to the other, which is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104910/system-drawing-color-system-windows-media-color), and then use the '==' operator.
2. Compare the individual components. Since both of them have the R, G, B, A properties as bytes, you can simply do:

   ```
   bool ColorsEqual (System.Drawing.Color c1, System.Windows.Media.Color c2)
   {
       return c1.R == c2.R && c1.G == c2.G 
           && c1.B == c2.B && c1.A == c2.A;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no `operator==` overloaded for these two types, you could acquire the string-values of the color or the ARGB-values.

```
System.Drawing.Color c1 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,0);
System.Windows.Media.Color c2 = System.Windows.Media.Color(255,0,0,0);
if(c1.A == c2.A && c1.R == c2.R && ...
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension method to the System.Drawing.Color that converts to a System.Windows.Media.Color and then compare on the System.Windows.Media.Color type:

```
public static System.Windows.Media.Color ToMediaColor(this System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    return System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```